# Воспроизвести видео / показать Ip

Tags: php

```
switch (md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    case $IpAgent:
        //Показать Ip
    default:
        Тут нужно видео вывести!
    }
```

Возможно ли при нужном юзерагенте вывести Ip адрес,а в остальных случаях показывать нужное видео

!PHP

Comment: Можно, разрешаю, выводите!

Comment: @Other я имею ввиду подсказать как

Comment: Ну Вы на правильном пути. В принципе. Если заголовок отвечает представлениям о требуемом - делаем это в блоке, иначе что-то другое.

Comment: @Other :D, lool